# Why are there extra pipes coming out of the ground?

Tags: plumbing

Is there any reason for all of these water pipes to be here? There are four coming out of the ground on the right, that all just connect to each other before going anywhere, and the three on the left that also all connect to eachother before going anywhere.

Behind this wall is a sink for a bathroom, and on this side of the wall there is currently nothing but was a sink at one point in the past for a wet bar. The pipes that go off to the left go no where, but my best guess for that is that the bathroom used to have a double sink since thats about where the second sink would be if there was one.
[image: Pipes]

Comment: Those pipes either used to supply something or still do. Where else do you have water faucets (clothes washing machine, dishwasher, outdoor garden faucets, garage, shop, etc.)?

Comment: @JimmyFix-it So do you mean that the larger one coming up is the supply, then the extra ones are going back down to supply something else? I guess i'm confused why they would split above ground like that.  There is a laundry machine a room over, and a shower in the same room the sink is in. Besides that there is nothing else on the bottom floor besides the kitchen sink which is not supplied from this for sure.

Comment: Ok lets recap. one line in (large 3/4) is prob Cold Water in. 1 Line out is Cold Water to Water Heater, 1 Line is Cold water to rest of house. (probably lines on the right are cold water). Lines on Left are probably hot water. Exact configuration I can't say - maybe your building permit has the drawings..

Answer (score 3):

> **I guess i'm confused why they would split above ground like that.**

That's the sort of thing that can happen when a property is altered. Maybe the building originally had fewer washbasins etc on that floor and more were added. Rather than lifting the floor and making connections in cramped dark dirty spaces the plumber felt it was easier to make the solder connections in a more accessible space where his blowtorch was also less likely to set fire to nearby joists and accumulated dust and detritus.

Answer (score 2):

It’s a manifold. You aren’t allowed to make connections under The slab so water from the service comes in. Runs to one bathroom then they make a manifold and the other water lines will run to another bathroom, kitchen, etc.